# How can I uncomment "#" a line using python?

Tags: python, scripting

I looking for this

```
#My line    <=== is commented
```

after running my python script

```
My line     <=== is uncommented
```

IS there any way to get an executable code by reading a commented line?

Comment: Wyh not "if...then" statement?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

apart from if-then clauses, no.
It's commented code for a reason, and that reason is for the interpreter to ignore it at all times.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, but not very useful. The following naive code attempts to change line 4 of its text block within Blender. The function `modify` takes 4 arguments.

- `name` - the file name of the script
- `lineno` - the line number to change (zero based)
- `orig` - the original start of the string to change
- `repl` - the replacement

So if you execute the script twice, the code will be commented again. The script will attempt to find its own file name in the last 2 lines. Only tested for Linux.

```
import bpy
import ntpath
#this is a comment
#print("Hello Blender!") # this is code

def modify(name, lineno, orig, repl):
    t = bpy.data.texts[name]
    s = t.as_string()
    l = s.splitlines()

    if l[lineno].startswith(orig):
        l[lineno] = l[lineno].replace(orig, repl, 1)
    elif l[lineno].startswith(repl):
        l[lineno] = l[lineno].replace(repl, orig, 1)

    t.from_string("\n".join(l))

head, tail = ntpath.split(__file__)
modify(tail or ntpath.basename(head),3,"#print","print")
```